# css variables - confused?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm running chrome 35.

I'm quite confused by the css variables. I need to use css variables for my apps. For example,

```
.A{
  var-myVar:red;
  background-color:var(var-myVar);
  font-color:var(var-myVar);
}
```

However, I found 3 different css vairable syntaxes, none of which seem to work:

```
var-myVar //doesn't seem to work

--myVar //doesn't seem to work

-webkit-var-myVar //doesn't seem to work
```

So naturally I'm confused.

I saw that some recommended to turn on some css flags - but there aren't any significant css flags to turn on.

Thank you

Comment: Did you enable CSS variables through experimental WebKit features?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only Firefox supports [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). If you want to use CSS Variables, I would recommend you use a CSS preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the only browser supporting CSS3 variables is Mozilla Firefox: [http://caniuse.com/#search=css variables](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables).
In earlier versions of Chrome you were able to set the `#enable-experimental-webkit-features` flag in order to enable CSS3 variables for testing purposes. But this option's gone.

According to the [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/) the correct way of using the variables is:

```
:root {
    --borderRadius:10px;
}

...
#foo {
    border-radius:var(--borderRadius);
}
```

However, a global support of 0.21% should be a reason for avoiding the usage of CSS3 variables at the moment.
If you wish to make your development easier, you may wish to use CSS preprocessors like SASS or LESS.